# Using an internet hosted server as a proxy server

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, nat

I have been hunting around for an answer to this and created some IPtable rules but have not found exactly what I am after.

I host a service which clients connect to, but due to a one customer complication, I need them to connect twice from the same public IP address which hits a problem on our end. So I need them to come from a different public IP address. Usually, it looks like this (details have been changed);

Client at 50.10.10.1 connects to our server 60.60.10.1 via TCP 1234

In order to allow the client to connect twice, I thought I can spin up an EC2 instance which they connect through, and this will replace the source IP address with that of the instance; so it looks like they are coming from somewhere else. It would look like this;

A client at 50.10.10.1 connects to our instance at 30.20.10.1 via TCP 1234. The instance then replaces the source IP address to be 30.20.10.1 and then forwards the packets to 60.60.10.1 TCP 1234

I can find ways of doing this with an internal proxy server, like squid or just a firewall rule, but I can't figure out how to do this with an EC2 instance sitting on the internet with IPTables. Does anyone have any recommendations? I found a recommendation of this rule but it's not working;

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -d 30.20.10.1  --dport 1234 -s 50.10.10.1  -j DNAT --to-destination 60.60.10.1:1234
```